# CardField won't display Stripe Payment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, expo, stripe-payments

[image]
I am trying to implement stripe payment method I was following a youtube tutorial and at a certain point he got his CardField to UI to display but mine still won't work I don't know where I went wrong.

```
const CheckOutScreen = () => {
      const [eamil, setEmail] = useState();
      const [cardDetails, setCardDetails] = useState();
      //const [confirmPayment, loading] = useConfirmPayment();
      const [publishableKey, setPublishableKey] = useState('');

  return (
    <StripeProvider publishableKey={publishableKey}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onChangeText={(value) => setEmail(value.nativeEvent.text)}
          autoCapitalize="none"
        ></TextInput>

        <CardField
          postalCodeEnabled={true}
          placeholder={{
            number: "4242 4242 4242 4242",
          }}
          style={styles.card}
          cardStyle={styles.cardContainer}
          onCardChange={(cardDetails) => {
            setCardDetails(cardDetails);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </StripeProvider>
  );
};
```

Here Is my Server side of things I am using express framework I'm not sure if it's a server issue or not.

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: The first step would be to open the JS console in your browser's developer tools to look at any message/error raised there. If an Element doesn't appear, it's usually because something in your code is not initialized properly such as the wrong API key, or not loading Stripe.js first and the error message would point you to the issue

Comment: @koopajah I have attached an image of the error I am getting

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have much information to help you debug this I'm sorry. It doesn't look like it even renders the view at all. Have you tried showing something that isn't Stripe on your page first?

Comment: @koopajah unfortunately it's part of the feature I have to add in my project

Comment: I understand that you want to accept payments. But right now your view isn't loading at all and I am not convinced it's a Stripe issue and more a configuration issue where your code is not even loading the first page/view. I'd recommend ignoring Stripe for a few hours and focusing on making a basic example/text appear client-side first.